# List of named captures / groups in boost regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, named, capture-group

I want to know how I can get the name(s) of capture group(s) in a regular expression in boost.

For example, if a user inputs a string which is expected to be a valid regex with named capture groups, how can one iterate through the list of defined groups in the regex and get the names of those groups. Does boost provide facilities to do so, or I am expected to write my own parser to extract those names?

As an example, if the input string is:

```
(?<year>[0-9]{4}).*(?<month>[0-9]{2}).*(?<day>[0-9]{2})
```

I want to be able to extract "year","month", and "day" out of the regex.

Comment: Possibly you could compile the regex into a boost regex, then get the capture names from it. You could do this but there is an issue with named sub expressions. Technically, when the regex is parsed, each name is turned into a hash and dropped into a vector,  where further reference is via an id. Take a look at `class named_subexpressions` in boost_regex.hpp. It can be modified to create an map of the actual string names. Where you can add a call to get the group indexed name back.

Comment: (Sorry, the source should be basic_regex.hpp) I can post the few lines that does this, but you'd have to recompile the engine. And I'm not really sure if this is legal.

Comment: It would be something like this `classnamed_subexpressions{public:...voidset_name(constcharT*i,constcharT*j,intindex){...std::stringstmp(i,j);intalen=(int)stmp.length();if(alen>0){longest_name=alen>longest_name?alen:longest_name;m_sub_sNames[index]=stmp;}}std::stringget_name(intndx)const{if(longest_name>0){autogroupName=m_sub_sNames.find(ndx);if(groupName!=m_sub_sNames.end())returngroupName->second;}return"";}intget_longest_namelen(){returnlongest_name;}private:intlongest_name;std::map<int,std::string>m_sub_sNames;...};`

Comment: You'd iterate over the groups. Get the number of capture groups from regex object. grpnum = 0 - num_grps `std::string grpname = rxobj.get_named_subs()->get_name( grpnum ); if (grpname.length() > 0) { ...}`

Comment: @sln Thanks! good solution, but I doubt I get the permission to change the boost code in the repository... at least I know why initially I couldn't find the facility! It was simply not there! :-)

Comment: No need to change the boost library. The only way most use boost regex is to _link_ to the lib. However, you don't need to do this. Unpack the boost zip local to your machine. Copy the regex source files from here _(root)\boost\regex\v4 (all are hpp files)_ into your app's directory. Set an include path to _(root)_. Set these preprossor defines _BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB\nBOOST_REGEX_NON_RECURSIVE\nBOOST_REGEX_BLOCKSIZE=32768\nBOOST_REGEX_MAX_BLOCKS=8192\nBOOST_REGEX_MAX_CACHE_BLOCKS=4096\n_. Then you're all set, just recompile. Instant regex, no need to link to boost libs. Adds an extra 300k to app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex:

```
"\?<([^<>]+)>"
```

I don't think that regex engines provide such ability to give you the names of the captured groups before compiling the regex, because it needs to traverse the input regex once before parsing (and compiling) the regex which is not a optimum method, unless it compile the regex once and does all the jobs together.

So, with regards to your comment, if it's possible that you have an unnamed group you better to loop over your captured groups and see if it has name or not.

Note that maybe you could pars the cases that have unnamed groups with regex, but I don't think that it is a general way.

For example you can use the aforementioned regex within parenthesis to capture all the groups that don't have another capture group in them (`[^()]*` will ensure that):

```
`\((\?<([^<>]+)>)[^()]*\)`
```

And for another cases you have to write another one.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was more curious to know if this is provided by regex engines or not. I tried to find such facility but in vain. Do you have any idea how to find which capture-group the extracted name belongs to? suppose the second capture group is not named in the input regex... `(?<year>[0-9]{4}).*([0-9]{2}).*(?<day>[0-9]{2})`  can we find out that day actually refers to the third capture-group?